# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE when load https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/webworker.js

Tags: recaptcha

Sometimes when render reCAPTCHA widget, it will report an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE` from `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/anchor` when load `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/webworker.js`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuZQ0.png)

And we can reproduce this by refresh the page again and again (use document demo code):

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : ' site_key',
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any news on this ?